# Adding knob LABEL inside jquery knob input value(not asking for percentage)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-knob

I'm using jQuery plugin called Jquery Knob to create circular progress chart.
I've achieved to show value and percentage but I also want to show a label inside the knob itself.This is what I've achieved: [without label](https://image.ibb.co/ia9hoQ/ds.png)
and this is what I want to achieve: [with label](https://image.ibb.co/nHQGF5/jquery_plugin_circliful.jpg)

I've used the following code but don't know how to add a text on next line to percentage value(inside knob)

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

        $(element).knob({
            'format': function(value) {
                return value + '%';
            }
        });
}
```

I tried adding a newline like

```
return value + "%\nlabel"
```

but it doesn't work and comes on the same line.

Answer (score 1):

i think i've figured the answer. if u read the documentation, jQuery knob has **draw** method. jQuery knob use canvas to made the circle, so u just add canvas text to the canvas context. This is should be the answer that match to your need:

```
$(element).knob({
   'format': function(value) {
      return value + '%';
   },
   'draw': function() {
      this.g.fillText('label', x, y)
   }
});
```

adjust the x and y variable to the point u will put the label
eg. if u want it below the knob value, u should put y >= 1/2 height of your knob.

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved your requirement by using [jQuery roundSlider](http://roundsliderui.com/). Check the below demo:

### [`DEMO`](http://jsfiddle.net/soundar24/LpuLe9tr/975/)

Comment: Yes there are many other plugins through which it can be done easily but I want to get this done using jquery Knob.

Comment: Do you have a jsFiddle for your sample, so that i can try to achieve the requirement through knob in that demo. Or do you have any specific reason for why you need to use knob alone ?